# ECC memory on 2nd Gen Intel i3

Tags: memory, nas, ecc

I'm in the process of collecting components for a NAS build. I've gone with an UNAS NSC-800 case and an Intel Server Board 1200KPR. I have an i3-2130 thats lying around that Id love to use instead of investing on a Xeon E3 processor.

Does 2nd gen i3 support ECC memory?  Being a NAS id like to have some reliability when it comes to the components.

Intel officially have said it doesn't support ECC but folks on forums have mentioned that it does. Any thoughts about this if anyone has experience with this chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough room in the comments to fit all this, here is what I have so far, it might save some reading for others.

The discussions on the web were indicating that now that the memory controller is on the CPU itself, on consumer CPU's Intel had disabled the ability of the memory controller to use ECC. Supposedly it was not disabled on the I3, but there was also indication that it was on I3 "server products" which would be the E3?

The wiki has this information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i3 , and some motherboard manufacture is saying Yes, but UDIMM is unbuffered  memory, usually for consumer.
For that (server) board http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1u/5016/sys-5016i-mrhf.cfm It can take either ECC or UDIMM.
The board is also a LGA 1156 Socket not an 1155

Previously the controllers were on the motherboard, and it would be up to the motherboard maker , and memory controller chip to include that or not.
  Most of the server boards were set up for ECC capability, even if (usually) this feature could be disabled, and regular memory used.  (Add in buffered and registered to the mix and it is a lengthy discussion.)

As examples of Intel supported ECC, One person posted this http://ark.intel.com/compare/27749,27746,27747,34474,33142, comparison chart of the Intel chipsets memory controllers showing support for ECC.  The 5000X ,5000P, 5000V, 5100, and 5400 memory controllers, all showing they support ECC.

Back to the front of the site http://ark.intel.com/ to start again.

Now we use the same site, to find the **1200KPR** Server motherboard. http://ark.intel.com/products/67346/Intel-Server-Board-S1200KPR Which once again states that ECC is supported.  It is a "server" product.  The motherboard supports ECC.
 Note: being a server board there is some sort of graphics ability onboard. It is LGA 1155 socket

Back again, we enter into Desktop Processors. . .  Hey wait, why are we going all server board, and server memory, then trying to shove a desktop processor in? Xeons are not that much more relative to their feature set?   Lets take a look at the **I3-2130** anyway.  http://ark.intel.com/products/53428/Intel-Core-i3-2130-Processor-3M-Cache-3_40-GHz
Specifically the 2nd Gen Intel I3 desktop processor, and no ECC support information is shown in the data there.  It is FCLGA 1155 socket
 Note: being a consumer CPU it has the CPU/GPU combo.
Cost ~$130 USD

As we back up again, and move to the server line, the similar **E3-1270** for LGA 1155 socket is a 8Mcache 3.40ghz, that does say it supports ECC. http://ark.intel.com/products/52276/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1270-8M-Cache-3_40-GHz.
Note: being a server CPU there is no GPU in the package.
Costs ~$330 USD
Because it is a server data speed can be more important than processing speed, so a small step down ,Intel Xeon E3-1220 3.1GHz LGA 1155 , for example is ~$200 USD

Side notes: data sheets are not always accurate, because some copy pasting can occur, that does not apply.

This is all I have so far, and is subject to correction.

Comment: So in other words; don't be a cheapskate. Buy the ECC RAM. See if it works. If it doesn't work, spend the extra $200 on a known, working E3 processor rather than recycling a processor you have that might or might not work.

Comment: @MarkHenderson , Good idea, buy it try it.  most of what I am seeing looks like rumor building from the web.

Answer (score -1):

I have the 1200KPR mobo with an i3-3220T and one stick of Kingston KVR16E11/8 ECC RAM.  memtest86+ and FreeBSD dmidecode say ECC is supported.

Comment: He's asking about the 2nd-gen i3 (i3-2xxx), while your information is for a 3rd-gen (i3-3xxx).